# How to change the NavDrawer icon in specific fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Well, in my application I have a fragment that is responsible for displaying news calls, and that fragment is also an item in my Navigation Drawer.

The user can click on the news calls and then enter a new fragment.

What I want is that when the user enters this new fragment, which has the news, the icon that was before of the NavDrawer, turn a return arrow.

**This is the fragment that holds the calls to the news**
[image: This is the fragment that holds the calls to the news]

**This is the news fragment, which should have the return arrow**
[image: This is the news fragment, which should have the return arrow]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

in fragment override onCreate method like this

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true); // note this line
    }
```

then override onActivityCreated method like this

```
  @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // this is your back arrow

    }
```

and at last for click of an back arrow override onOptionsItemSelected method

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id) {
            case android.R.id.home:

                if (getActivity() != null)
                    getActivity().onBackPressed();

                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
```

Done! Hope this is what you wanted..